# Tring to get one item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello i'm trying to get one item from list but idk to do that

this is my code:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/media/archsohee/Music/"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".flac"):
            fldr = (os.path.join(file))
            lk = fldr.split(',')[0]
            print(lk)
        elif file.endswith(".mp3"):
            print(os.path.join(file))
```

The output:

```
08 - Mac DeMarco - Dreams from Yesterday.flac
03 - Mac DeMarco - Baby You're Out.flac
01 - itssvd - Love Again.flac
Save Yourself (Japanese Version) - ONE OK ROCK.flac
03 - Philip Pors Jepsen - Trust Nobody.flac
04 - Mac DeMarco - For the First Time.flac
09 - Arctic Monkeys - Why'd You Only Call Me When You're High-.flac
10 - Mac DeMarco - Go Easy.flac
11 - Mac DeMarco - On the Level.flac
04 - Mac DeMarco - Let Her Go.flac
09 - Mac DeMarco - Chamber Of Reflection.flac
06 - Mac DeMarco - Still Beating.flac
02 - Philip Pors Jepsen - My Sin.flac
```

i want to get one of them like "11 - Mac DeMarco - On the Level.flac"

Comment: You have no control flow statements which end the loop; your code will loop until it's done. You have to put in some kind of stopping condition.

Comment: how do you want to choose which one you get?  by index position?  by text match?

Comment: @RandomDavis is return stopping condition?

Comment: @VargaIgnacio yes, it is _a_ stopping condition

Comment: @Anentropic yeah i think by index position

Comment: `return` will exit the loop if you are inside a function, else use `break`

Comment: `files` is a list so just get the element you want by indexing into the list e.g. to get the fourth file use `filename = files[3]` (index numbers start at zero) ... no need for the `for` loop if you only want that one item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an item from a list you need a *list*. Your code is just printing the file name.

**First, create a list:**

```
import os 

path = "media/archsohee/Music"
file_list = [] #create an empty list that we'll append our files too.

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if '.flac' in file: #if filename contains ".flac" add it to our list.
            file_list.append(file)

print(file_list)
```

**Then... perform an operation on the list:**

From here, you can perform operations on the list. For example get the first item in the list or create a new list with only songs by Mac DeMarco.

```
print(file_list[0]) #this returns the first item in the list

mac_demarco_songs = [file for file in file_list if 'Mac DeMarco' in file] #note that "Mac Demarco" is case sensitive.
print(mac_demarco_songs) #prints our list of Mac DeMarco songs.
```